# Correct implementation for property of all objects that are equal

Tags: java, oop

## The problem

Consider an implementation of a graph, `SampleGraph<N>`.
Consider an implementation of the graph nodes, `Node extends N`, correctly overriding `hashCode` and `equals` to mirror logical equality between two nodes.

Now, let's say we want to add some property *p* to a node. Such a property is bound to logical instances of a node, i.e. for `Node n1, n2`, `n1.equals(n2)` implies *p(`n1`)* = *p(`n2`)*

If I simply add the property as a field of the `Node` class, this has happened to me:

- I define `Node n1, n2` such that `n1.equals(n2)` but `n1 != n2`
- I add `n1` and `n2` to a graph: `n1` when inserting the logical node, and `n2` when referencing to the node during insertion of edges. The graph stores both instances.
- Later, I retrieve the node from the graph (`n1` is returned) and set the property *p* on it to some value. Later, I traverse all the edges of the graph, and retrieve the node from one of them (`n2` is returned). The property *p* is not set, causing a logical error in my model.

To summarize, **current behavior**:

```java
graph.addNode(n1) // n1 is added
graph.addEdge(n2,nOther) // graph stores n2
graph.queryForNode({query}) // n1 is returned
graph.queryForEdge({query}).sourceNode() // n2 is returned
```

## The question

All the following statements seem reasonable to me. None of them fully convinces me over the others, so I'm looking for best practice guidelines based on software engineering canons.

**S1** - The graph implementation is poor. Upon adding a node, the graph should always internally check if it has an instance of the same node (`equals` evaluates to true) memorized. If so, such instance should always be the only reference used by the graph.

```java
graph.addNode(n1) // n1 is added
graph.addEdge(n2,nOther) // graph internally checks that n2.equals(n1), doesn't store n2
graph.queryForNode({query}) // n1 is returned
graph.queryForEdge({query}).sourceNode() // n1 is returned
```

**S2** - Assuming the graph behaves as in S1 is a mistake. The programmer should take care that always the same instance of a node is passed to the graph.

```java
graph.addNode(n1) // n1 is added
graph.addEdge(n1,nOther) // the programmer uses n1 every time he refers to the node
graph.queryForNode({query}) // n1 is returned
graph.queryForEdge({query}).sourceNode() // n1 is returned
```

**S3** - The property is not implemented the right way. It should be an information which is external to the class `Node`. A collection, such as a `HashMap<N, Property>`, would work just fine, treating different instances as the same object based on `hashCode`.

```java
HashMap<N, Property> properties;

graph.addNode(n1) // n1 is added
graph.addEdge(n2,nOther) // graph stores n2
graph.queryForNode({query}) // n1 is returned
graph.queryForEdge({query}).sourceNode() // n2 is returned

// get the property. Difference in instances does not matter
properties.get(n1)
properties.get(n2) //same property is returned
```

**S4** - Same as S3, but we could hide the implementation inside `Node`, this way:

```java
class Node {
  private static HashMap<N, Property> properties;

  public Property getProperty() {
    return properties.get(this);
  }
}
```

**Edit**: added code snippets for current behavior and tentative solutions following [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061890/2055152). To clarify, the whole example comes from using a real graph data structure from an open source Java project.

Comment: S4 doesn't seem like a good option to me. S3 could be quite complex and could only be worthwhile if you need that decoupling (e.g. if the data can be quite different for nodes). S2 would be ok but might result in some places where it doesn't happen (dev's mistake etc.). So IMO S1 would be the way to go while S2 could supplement that in order to not create unnecessary instances.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. I'm not sure I understand your comment on S3, as properties are supposed to be different for each logical node.

Comment: Well, S4 isn't a good option partly because of that static map. If S3 would be similar just with some other class holding the map you'd still have the same problem. So using a proper cache/repository would be advised. Additionally you'd have to handle loading and eviciting properties whenever you load or remove a node which might get quite complex. Not doing so properly might result in lookup failures (aka cache missed) or nodes not being garbage collected if they're just removed from the graph (since at least the cache/repo would still hold a reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my mind, it comes down choosing between APIs with strong or weak abstraction.

- If you choose strong abstraction, the API would hide the fact that `Node` objects have identity, and would canonicalize them when they are added to the `SimpleGraph`.
- If you choose weak abstraction, the API would assume that `Node` objects have identity, and it would be up to the caller to canonicalize them before adding them to the `SimpleGraph`.

The two approaches lead to different API contracts and require different implementation strategies.  The choice is likely to have performance implications ... if that is significant.

Then there are finer details of the API design that may or may not match your specific use-case for the graphs.

The point is that you need to make the choice.

(This a bit is like deciding to use the collections `List` interface and its clean model, versus implementing your own linked list data structure so that you can efficiently "splice" 2 lists together.  Either approach *could* be correct, depending on the requirements of your application.)

Note that you usually *can* make a choice, though the choice may be a difficult one.  For example, if you are using an API designed by someone else:

- You can choose to use it as-is.  (Suck it up!)
- You can choose to *try to* influence the design.  (Good luck!)
- You can choose to switch to a different API; i.e. a different vendor.
- You can choose to fork the API and adjust it to your own requirements (or preferences if this is what this is about)
- You can choose to design and implement your own API from scratch.

And if you *really* don't have a choice, then this question is moot.  Just use the API.

---

If this is a open-source API then you probably don't have the choice of getting the designers to change it.  Significant API overhauls have a tendency of creating a lot of work for other people; i.e. the many *other* projects that depend on the API.  A responsible API designer / design team takes this into account.  Or else they find that they lose relevance because their APIs get a reputation for being unstable.

So ... if you are aiming to influence an existing open-source API design ... 'cos you think they are doing it incorrectly (for some definition of incorrect) ... you are probably better off "forking" the API and dealing with the consequences.

---

And finally, if you are looking for "best practice" advice, be aware that [there are no best practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).  And this is not just a philosophical issue.  This is about why you will get screwed if you go asking for / looking for "best practice" advice, and then follow it.

---

As a footnote: have you ever wondered why the Java and Android standard class libraries don't offer any general-purpose graph APIs or implementations?  And why they took such a long time to appear in 3rd party libraries (Guava version 20.0)?

The answer is that there is no consensus on what such an API should be like.  There are just too many conflicting use-cases and requirement sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the code snippets, I hope they help clarifying the question. I also agree with your statement (`The point is that you need to make the choice`), but in this case I have no control on the implementation of `SampleGraph`, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Let's delete this conversation.  It is going nowhere,

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for your detailed updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that S1 makes the most sense.  Some Graph implementations internally use a `Set<Node>` (or some equivalent) to store the nodes.  Of course, using a structure like a `Set` will ensure that there are no duplicate `Node`s, where `Node n1` and `Node n2` are considered duplicates if and only if `n1.equals(n2)`.  Of course, the implementation of `Node` should ensure that all relevant properties are considered when comparing two instances (ie. when implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`).

Some of the issues with the other statements:

S2, while perhaps reasonable, yields an implementation in which the *burden falls to the client* to understand and safeguard against a potential pitfall of the internal Graph implementation, which is a clear sign of a poorly designed API for the Graph object.

S3 and S4 both seem weird, although perhaps I don't quite understand the situation.  In general, if a `Node` holds on to some data, it seems perfectly reasonable to define a member variable inside class `Node` to reflect that.  Why should this extra property be treated any differently?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had exactly the same idea about S3 and S4, that `static` sounds funny. As I was using classes that were externally provided (I wrote `Node`, but not `SampleGraph`), I wasn't sure of where the error was, so I tried to think of possible fixes.

Comment: `Why should this extra property be treated any differently?` Just to fix the problem, merging different instances into the same object with the same logic of `equals`. Looks bad, works fine. S4 is the one I implemented in the end (even though I'm learning here that is not best practice).